# Как экспортировать данные полученные с помощью fetch?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Есть Fetch запрос, ответ которого передается в аргумент функции:

```
fetch('url')
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(
    response => {
        getDataFromAPI(response)
    },
    error => alert(`Rejected: ${error}`)
    );
export function getDataFromAPI(data) {
   console.log(data)
}
```

Как мне нужно ее импортировать чтобы получить данные в нескольких других файлах?

Answer (score -1):

Почему бы просто данные не записать в константу и вытягивать из других файлов эту константу(как глобальное состояние)?

```
export const myData = [];
fetch('url')
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(
    response => {
        getDataFromAPI(response)
    },
    error => alert(`Rejected: ${error}`)
    );
export function getDataFromAPI(data) {
   myData = data; // через константу
   return data; // или можно через функцию вернуть данные туда куда вам необходимо.
}
```

Что-бы получить эти данные, вы должны написать в ваших других файлах

```
import {myData, getDataFromAPI} from 'filePath';
```

Так же можете вызвать сам fetch и вернуть данные в компонент. Вот пример:

```
export function getDataFromAPI() {
    fetch('url')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(
        response => {
            return response;
        },
        error => alert(`Rejected: ${error}`)
        );
}
```

Comment: Само тело функции выводит . но именно data - нет

Comment: Можете записать куда-то данные, как я предлагал через константу.
Или вы можете после вызова fetch вернуть response тому компоненту(файлу) от которого вы вызываете этот fetch (но опять же вам нужно использовать не в одном файле эти данные). Вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию которая принимает данные на вход и возвращает эти данные. Но после вызова функции и вы ей ничего не предадите функция вернет саму себя, Кэп. Ваш идеальный способ это глобальное состояние :).